# Compute a magnitude using a function that depends on the type of a data.table row

Tags: r, data.table

I want to compute a magnitude that depends on the type of a data.table row:

```
library (data.table)

n1 <- c(1,2,3)
n2 <- c(10,20,30,40)
num <- list(n1,n2)
type <- c("price", "volume") 
dt1 <- data.table (num, type)
dt1 [, cons.fun := "sum"]
dt1[type=="price", cons.fun := "mean"]

> dt1
           num   type cons.fun
1:       1,2,3  price     mean
2: 10,20,30,40 volume      sum
```

Thus, I need to create a new column `magnitude` based on the `cons.fun` value. I tried:

`dt1 [, magnitude:=match.fun(cons.fun)(num)]`, and got the error:

```
Error in match.fun(cons.fun) : 
  'c("mean", "sum")' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Instead of the expected:

```
> dt1
           num   type cons.fun magnitude
1:       1,2,3  price     mean         2
2: 10,20,30,40 volume      sum       100
```

How can I get it right? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.  Loop through the rows, `get` the value of the string and apply the function on the 'num' column

```
dt1[, magnitude := get(cons.fun)(num[[1]]), 1:nrow(dt1)]
dt1
#          num   type cons.fun magnitude
#1:       1,2,3  price     mean         2
#2: 10,20,30,40 volume      sum       100
```

---

Or as the OP was using `match.fun`, 'cons.fun' can be looped with `mapply` to extract the function object and to apply the function  on the corresponding `list` column 'num'

```
dt1[, magnitude := mapply(function(x, y) match.fun(x)(y), cons.fun, num)]
```

Comment: Dear @akrun, I cannot find in the data.table syntax docs the reasoning for the third parameter `1:nrow(dt1)`. AFAIK it should be preceeded by `by=`, `on=` etc. What does exactly it do? Thank you.

Comment: @FabioCorrea Here the `1:nrow(dt1)` is for the `by` parameter i.e. we are groouping by row